# How to convert from YUV to RGB in Python? (different vector sizes)

Tags: python, rgb, type-conversion, yuv

I have a Input image with 640*1176 pxls and I'm reading it out as YUV Format from a protobuf message. What I get are three vectors Y,U,V with different lengths:

Y has 1.310.720 elements
U has   163.840 elements
V has   163.840 elements

Y is 8 time larger than U or V ...

I want to know how to convert them to RGB format. I don't know how to combine the Y,U,V channel together because of their different size.

Comment: How is your original YUV format created? It's like that U and V are [subsampled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). If that's the case, you want to upsample the chroma channels so you can combine everything together.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have actually no information about the Input. What do you mean with combining them together? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Assuming I'm correct about the subsampling (that 8 factor makes it look highly possible), you have to upsample the chrome channels so that they have the same number of elements as Y. Then there is a simple formula that converts YUV to RGB. That's what I meant by combining them together. However, I'm still perplexed how a 640x1176 image can result in 1310720 Y elements. I would expect that from a 1280x1024 image, for example. Maybe your original image was resized before it was converted and stored in YUV?

Comment: I was woundering about the length, too! That didn't make sense to me, it probably was resized as u say. I will try the upsampling out